# Why is the ANOVA p-value <.0001 even though the means are identical?

Tags: r, anova, panel-data

I am trying to use ANOVA on rank transformed data. Here is a summary of my dataset after omitting `NA` values:

```
> summary(PD_sande)
   subject_id  timepoint     sande       
 320001 :  3      : 0    Min.   : 60.00  
 1160001:  3   V02:41    1st Qu.:100.00  
 1190001:  3   V03:41    Median :100.00  
 1480001:  3   V04:43    Mean   : 98.56  
 1570001:  3             3rd Qu.:100.00  
 1730001:  3             Max.   :100.00  
 (Other):107
```

There are no differences (at least as far as I can tell) in the mean value of `sande` between `V02` and `V03`:

```
> PD_sande %>%
+   get_summary_stats(sande, type = "mean_se")
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  timepoint variable     n  mean    se
  <fct>     <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 V02       sande       41  98.5 1.02 
2 V03       sande       41  98.5 1.02 
3 V04       sande       43  98.6 0.975
```

`sande` is an ordinal variable. Thus I am using a rank transformation prior to attempting ANOVA:

```
rsande<-rank(PD_sande$sande)
```

Here is the problem as I see it. Once I create my model on the rank transformed data and try to run ANOVA, I am told there is a significant difference between timepoints V02 and V03:

```
> rsande
  [1] 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5  6.5  6.5  6.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5
 [32] 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5
 [63] 67.5  2.0  2.0  2.0 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5  6.5  6.5  6.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5
 [94] 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5 67.5
[125] 67.5
> lme.rank <- lme(fixed=rsande ~ timepoint, random=~1|subject_id, data=PD_sande)
> anova(lme.rank)
            numDF denDF     F-value p-value
(Intercept)     1    80 614.8824209  <.0001
timepoint       2    80 370.0903888  <.0001
> marginal = emmeans(lme.rank, ~ timepoint)
> pairs(marginal, adjust = "tukey")
 contrast  estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value
 V02 - V03 2.22e-14 9.65e-16 80 22.958  <.0001 
 V02 - V04 2.30e-14 9.49e-16 80 24.242  <.0001 
 V03 - V04 8.55e-16 9.49e-16 80  0.900  0.6416
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's because the standard error of your timepoint effect is extremely small, i suggest to migrate this to cross validated since it is interpreting your model

Comment: It appears to me that you have 3 observations per subject, one with each treatment. So I think that if you want to use ranks, the ranking should be done separately for each subject; then a mixed model is not needed because the subject effects ate by definition all equal. But it appears there are other serious issues here: one is that it seems there are only 3 or 4 different measured responses in the entire dataset. Further, there are lots of missing data. I think you have a real mess on your hands.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your rsande values, almost all of them are 67.5 with a few exceptions being 2.0 and 6.5. Even though you converted them to rank, when you fit a mixed effect model (or simple linear model for that matter), they are going to fit a mean that corresponds to the rank of 67.5 as an intercept, and the resulting residuals /errors are going to be incredibly small.

You cannot use a linear regression, that requires more or less residuals to be normally distributed for this. Maybe ordinal regression, or modeling the probability of getting a score not 67.5 in each group, might be more useful

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing the scale. Right now, the differences have 14  0's after the decimal and the SE has 16 0's.  So, multiply everything by a billion and you'll see more clearly what is going on

Comment: I don't see how it adds zny meaning to analyze in trrms of 1000000000 times the rank. most of the ranks are tied, and any kind of regression model is just crazy.